# Debezium can not capture change from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium mongo connnect 1.4.2 on Kafka connect 2.2. And it seems 'collection.include.list' configuration is preventing Debezium getting the collection data change. If I delete the collection.include.list config, the capture will start work. But will apply on all the collections which I don't want.

Can anyone send me some example about how collection.include.list can be configured? I tried to input '<db_name>[.]<collection_name>' , however I keep on got this warning and no data was captured.

[2021-04-03 07:58:21,971] WARN After applying the include/exclude list filters, no changes will be captured. Please check your configuration! (io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSchema:96)
My config is like below:

```
{
  "name": "pipeline-mongo-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.hosts": "xxxx_host:3717",
    "mongodb.name": "pipeline_mongo",
    "mongodb.user": "xxxxxxx",
    "mongodb.password":"xxxxxx",
    "collection.include.list": "prod-datapipeline[.]*"
  }
}
```

Thanks!